# How to adjust spaces between lines

Tags: css, wordpress

In my site , there is a big space between each line .  This is the css portions of that section. I have tried line-height but it is not working there.

```
#site-generator a {
color: #5D45A3;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

You can check the site [here](http://beta.cpmfinancial.co.uk/)  . Check the footer area 'Latest News'. I would like to reduce the space between each post names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to remove the `height` property from here:

```
.widget-area ul li {
  font-size: 11px;
  /* height: 23px; */ /* <- remove */
}
```

and here:

```
.widget ul li {
  font-size: 11px;
  /* height: 16px; */ /* <- remove */
}
```

Or set these `height`s as `auto`

Answer (score 0):

For the post titles use

```
    #site-generator .widget_recent_entries a{
    line-height:14px;
    }
```

Comment: It is not working, I would like to reduce the space between single post name not between 2 posts . For example 'What is the maximum amount of money you can get tax free?' this shows in 2 lines and I would like to reduce the space between those , not between 2 post titles

Comment: @Proudion the line height is set by id so it overrides the class only values. This adjusted css should work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adapt the `height` value in your stylesheet to your needs.
Line-height should work to adjust the space between two lines.

```
.widget-area ul li {
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 16px; /* example */
    line-height: 0.8em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 in your favourite browser to access the developer console (I believe this works in the latest version of IE, FF and Chrome). Inspect the `a` element that has such an abnormal height. This shows that:

You are setting a line-height of `2.2em` on `#site-generator` in style.css. If that style is deleted, it uses a line-height of `1.625` for `body, input, textarea` in style.css.

The distance between two `li`'s in that menu is defined by `.widget-area ul li` and is `23px`. If that style is deleted, the css for `.widget ul li` is used instead with a height of `16px`.

You'll need to alter the first one to put the text of one link closer together. You'll need to alter the second one to put the different links closer together.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
.widget-area ul li {width:auto !important;line-height:18px;}
```